undefined variable laravel 11 (can't run two methods)
My previous search method was running well after I implemented the method for calculations
**i got error undefined variable $formulas
C:\xampp\htdocs\MedusaDashboard\resources\views\superadmin\search.blade.php :103
this is my controller**
`<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\DetailFormula;
use App\Models\Formula;
use App\Models\Produk;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->input('query');

        $formulas = Formula::whereHas('warna', function($q) use ($query){
                               $q->where('kode_warna', 'like', "%$query%");
                            })
                           ->orWhere('varian', 'like', "%$query%")
                           ->orWhereHas('user', function($q) use ($query) {
                               $q->where('name', 'like', "%$query%");
                           })
                           ->orWhereHas('warna', function($q) use ($query) {
                            $q->where('nama_warna', 'like', "%$query%");
                            })
                           ->orWhereHas('mobil', function($q) use ($query) {
                               $q->where('merek', 'like', "%$query%");
                           })
                           ->get();

        return view('superadmin.search', compact('formulas'));
    }

    public function Detailformula($id)
    {
    // Mencari detail formula berdasarkan idformula yang cocok dengan $id
    $detailFormula = DetailFormula::where('idformula', $id)->get();

    // Memeriksa apakah detail formula ditemukan
    if (!$detailFormula) {
        abort(404, 'Detail formula not found');
    }

    

    // Tampilkan halaman formulaSA.blade.php dengan data yang diperlukan
    return view('superadmin.formulaSA', compact('detailFormula'));
    }


    public function calculate(Request $request)
    {
    $amount = $request->input('amount');
    $unit = $request->input('unit');
    $idFormula = $request->input('idFormula'); // Ensure this input is passed from the form

    // Ambil data detail formula berdasarkan idFormula
    $detailFormula = DetailFormula::where('idformula', $idFormula)->get();

    if ($unit == 'gram') {
        $totalJumlah = $detailFormula->sum('jumlahdlmgr');
        $x = $amount / $totalJumlah;

        foreach ($detailFormula as $detail) {
            $detail->jumlahdlmgr = $detail->jumlahdlmgr * $x;
        }
    } elseif ($unit == 'liter') {
        $totalVolume = 0;
        foreach ($detailFormula as $detail) {
            $produk = Produk::where('kode_produk', $detail->kode_produk)->first();
            if ($produk) {
                $volume = ($detail->jumlahdlmgr / 1000) / $produk->massa_jenis;
                $totalVolume += $volume;
            }
        }

        $x = $amount / $totalVolume;

        foreach ($detailFormula as $detail) {
            $produk = Produk::where('kode_produk', $detail->kode_produk)->first();
            if ($produk) {
                $detail->jumlahdlmgr = $detail->jumlahdlmgr * $x;
            }
        }
    }

    // Tampilkan halaman formulaSA.blade.php dengan data yang diperbarui
    return view('superadmin.formulaSA', compact('detailFormula'));
    }

}`

this is my search.blade
`@if(request()->has('query') && !empty(request()->input('query')))
          <h2>Search Results for Formulas</h2>
          <br></br>
          @if ($formulas->isEmpty())
            <p>No formulas found.</p>
          @else
            <div class="row gy-4" id="search-results">
              @foreach($formulas as $formula)
                <a class="search-item" href="{{ route('formula.open', ['id' => $formula->id]) }}">
                    <!--<p>Pembuat: {{ $formula->user->name }}</p>-->
                    <p>{{ $formula->warna->kode_warna }} / {{ $formula->warna->nama_warna }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $formula->mobil->merek }} {{ $formula->mobil->model }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $formula->varian }}</p>
                </a>
              @endforeach
          </div>
          @endif
    @endif`

formulaSA.blade (implement calculate method)
`<table class="styled-table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Komponen</th>
                  <th>Jumlah (gram)</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              @foreach($detailFormula as $detail)
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{ $detail->produk->kode_produk }} ({{ optional($detail->coat)->jeniscoat }})</td>
                      <td>{{ $detail->jumlahdlmgr }} gr</td>
                  </tr>
              @endforeach
          </tbody>
      </table>
        <!-- Form untuk melakukan perhitungan -->
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('calculate') }}">
      @csrf
      <input type="hidden" name="idFormula" value="{{ $detailFormula->first()->idformula }}">
      <div class="input-group">
          <label for="amount">Masukkan jumlah yang diinginkan</label>
          <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Masukkan jumlah" required>
          <select id="unit" name="unit" required>
              <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih satuan</option>
              <option value="liter">Liter</option>
              <option value="gram">Gram</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit">Hitung</button>
      </div>
  </form>`

i was try change variable and check again the variable, I think it's just a little typo, i hope method search and calculate can run together

Before passing data to view have you check using dd($formulas) that the variable holds data?

Detailformula and calculate -- these two method pass the data to same view file  formulaSA with the same variable name detailFormula.This might cause issue. Change one of the variable name from any of the method might help.

post the entire stack trace in order to locate the error, and where is coming from? Likely you have included your search.blade in some other view.

@Subha if the variable does not contain data, it is still defined. If the query does not have results, it will return an empty collection or null.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The error is in my web.php and controller
This is the new routes and controller:
Route::get('/formula', [SearchController::class, 'showSearchForm'])->name('formula.search'); 
Route::get('/formula/search', [SearchController::class, 'search'])->name('formula.search.results'); 
Route::get('/formula/{id}', [SearchController::class, 'handleFormula'])->name('formula.open');



class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->input('query');

    // Simpan query dalam session
    $request->session()->put('search_query', $query);

    // Lakukan pencarian seperti sebelumnya
    $formulas = Formula::whereHas('warna', function($q) use ($query) {
                        $q->where('kode_warna', 'like', "%$query%");
                    })
                    ->orWhere('varian', 'like', "%$query%")
                    ->orWhereHas('user', function($q) use ($query) {
                        $q->where('name', 'like', "%$query%");
                    })
                    ->orWhereHas('warna', function($q) use ($query) {
                        $q->where('nama_warna', 'like', "%$query%");
                    })
                    ->orWhereHas('mobil', function($q) use ($query) {
                        $q->where('merek', 'like', "%$query%");
                    })
                    ->get();

    return view('superadmin.search', compact('formulas', 'query'));
}

public function showSearchForm(Request $request)
{
// Ambil query pencarian dari session
$query = $request->session()->get('search_query', '');

// Tampilkan halaman pencarian dengan query dari session
return view('superadmin.search', compact('query'));
}

I just add new routes and new method.
